# Audio is shifted 50ms after combining it with video using ffmpeg / avconv

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I have wav file in which sound starts exactly at 00:00:00 (checked with **sonic-visualiser**).
I also have mp4 file without audio and when I combine them with:

```
ffmpeg -i videoOnly.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental out.mp4
```

And then examine wav file generated from combined file:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 out.wav
```

I see 50ms of silence before actual sound starts. The videoOnly.mp4 doesn't have 'edts' atom, so it's not related to 'elst' atom.

The question is why audio is shifted and how to avoid that?

Comment: Which ffmpeg version are you using? Show the full banner.

Comment: Actually I was using avconv, however I figured it out. I will post answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I think this may be ffmpeg / avconv issue ...
The reason why I've mentioned 'edts' and 'elst' atoms is that I've replaced 'edts' with 'free' in hex editor and since 'elst' is inside of 'edts' I simply ignored it.

However I thought that maybe ffmpeg / avconv doesn't ignore it, so in next try I've replaced 'elst' with zeros in hex editor and did the same steps again.
The result was mp4 file with audio which doesn't have 50ms delay.

Here is avconv version which I was using:

```
avconv version 9.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Dec  7 2016 21:22:31 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```